# Hibernate can child class be parent at same time

Tags: hibernate

In my Application I have 3 entities. Z, A and B.

Z -> A is OneToMany and Z is the parent of A.
A -> B is OneToOne and A is the parent of B.

Is this technically possible to do? That an Entity can be a child and parent at the same time?

Entity Z:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Z")
public class Z {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "z")
    private Set<B> bSet;
```

Entity A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "z_id")
    private Z z;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    private B b;
```

Entity B:

```
@Entity
public class B{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_ID")
    private A a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a mistake in your code where you have a one to many relationship for Z->B. 
`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "z") 
private Set<B> bSet;`

Should be

`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "z") 
private Set<A> aSet;`

Still, this doesn't fully answer your question. Parent and child relationships are a part of inheritance, yet there is no inheritance between these classes.

1. Z is a parent of A.

`@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A extends Z {` needs to extend class Z.

class A will receive all of class Z's properties as is the nature of inheritance. 
So as you can see, this already is breaking our inheritance because class Z has a reference to A. Ideally, you should not extend Z in this case and forget that Z is a parent of A.

So short answer, technically this is not possible.